# How to write Unit Test for IValidatableObject Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing

I have created a ViewModel as below.

```
   public class ProjectViewModel: IValidatableObject
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Name")]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Start Date")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("End Date")]
        [Compare("EndDate")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Project States")]
        public List<ProjectStateViewModel> States { get; set; }
        public string PageTitle { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            List<ValidationResult> res = new List<ValidationResult>();
            if (EndDate <= StartDate)
            {
                res.Add( new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage.END_DATE_AFTER_START_DATE));
            }

            return res;
        }
    }
```

Also written the below test case

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException( typeof(ValidationException),"End Date must be greater than Start Date.")]
public void Create_New_Project_EndDate_Earlier_StartDate()
{
    ProjectViewModel model = new ProjectViewModel
    {
        ProjectID = 3,
        Name = "Test Project",
        StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1),
        States = new List<ProjectStateViewModel> { new ProjectStateViewModel { StateName = "Pending" } }
    };

    Task<ActionResult> task = _projectController.Edit(model);

    ViewResult result = task.Result as ViewResult;

}
```

it works fine when actual code executing in MVC app through browser.  But ModelState.IsValid returns always true in my Unit test and it fails.  **Later I understood that Validation is not executed by controller.**  Controller received the model after Validation happens so it'll have appropriate ModelState.  **My question is what should be my approach to write unit test for Model Validation or should I write it at all?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for being in hurry to post the question.  I found one approach [here](http://sweettam.blogspot.in/2011/08/test-driving-model-validation-in-aspnet_17.html) . I have modified the test as below:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException( typeof(ValidationException),"End Date must be greater than Start Date.")]
public void Create_New_Project_EndDate_Earlier_StartDate()
{
    ProjectViewModel model = new ProjectViewModel
    {
        ProjectID = 3,
        Name = "Test Project",
        StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1),
        States = new List<ProjectStateViewModel> { new ProjectStateViewModel { StateName = "Pending" } }
    };

    ValidationContext contex = new ValidationContext(model);
    Validator.ValidateObject(model, contex);

}
```

Answer (score 20):

You can just call the method directly and assert against it's results.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Create_New_Project_EndDate_Earlier_StartDate()
{
    ProjectViewModel model = new ProjectViewModel
    {
        ProjectID = 3,
        Name = "Test Project",
        StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1),
        States = new List<ProjectStateViewModel> { new ProjectStateViewModel { StateName = "Pending" } }
    };

    var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model);

    var results = model.Validate(validationContext);

    Assert.AreEqual(results.Count(), 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(results.First().ErrorMessage, "End Date must be greater than Start Date.");
}
```